# How to check a value is existing in a list of dictionarys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
   l = [{"1": "one", "2":"two"}, {"3": "three", "4":"four"}, {"5": "five", "6":"six"}]
```

I want to check the below value is exist in that list of dicts or not:

```
     a = "two"
```

I know we can do this by loop and get() method, I am expecting any alternate method.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [5]: l = [{"1": "one", "2":"two"}, {"3": "three", "4":"four"}, {"5": "five", "6":"six"}]
In [7]: any(["two" in i.values() for i in l])
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: You'd have my upvote if you could get rid of `[` & `]` (generator expressions & early exit)..

Answer (score 2):

How about this one-liner?

```
>>> l = [{"1": "one", "2":"two"}, {"3": "three", "4":"four"}, {"5": "five", "6":"six"}]
>>> any(y == "two" for x in l for y in x.values())
True
```